# intent call gallery to select image in android

Tags: android

The view to pick the picture is launched and I can select an image. But when it goes back to my app, the onActivityResult is never called (neither in the ActivityGroup nor in the Activity).

I have checked several questions just in case I was missing a receiver and I found this Pick an image from the Gallery . But all the flags seem to be off.

Comment: check this - http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2012/05/choose-image-from-gallary-and-display.html?updated-min=2012-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&updated-max=2013-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&max-results=7

Answer (score 0):

You must start intent to pick the picture by calling startActivityForResult intead of startActivty.

If you are doing that, then may be you could share some code to see what the problem is.